# First call of the day to C# webservice very slow - analysis

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

This question is really around analysis - how do I analyze what's causing the problem?

**Situation** - we have a C# webservice configured through IIS 7.5, and a website in the same intranet domain hitting the webservice with POST and GET methods. Server is windows 2008 r2 64-bit, C# is 4.0. The first call of the day is slow (30-60 seconds), though I have not checked if I try again later in the day is it slow as well. Subsequent calls are 2-3 seconds. When checked using FireFox web console or firebug, the time is spent on "Waiting" for the webservice.

Things I've tried :-

- Setting no recycle time for the webservice AppPool
- Setting no idle time-out for the webservice AppPool
- Setting proxy bypassonlocal = true and usesystemdefault = false in case it's a proxy look up issue

Nothing's worked so far. My thought is that even if it's C# compile to machine code on first run, it shouldn't 'expire' if the AppPool does not time-out or recycle, yet it is slow everyday.

So flat out of options, how do I go about trying to find the source of the problem? Any diagnostics I can run on the server to check what the webservice is doing?

Comment: What kind of web service? ASMX?

Comment: RESTFUL / http endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it sounds as if your webservice might be going to sleep given the first call after a period of inactivity is slow and subsequent calls are faster.

I've seen this behaviour occur on many of my .NET IIS applications, can be frustrating to say the least!

This is however, default .NET behaviour, but there are ways of keeping your application awake, especially as of .NET4.

I refer you to the following article as a first step. Give it a go and see if this makes any difference for you:
https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/05/speeding-up-your-application-with-the-iis-auto-start-feature/

Good luck!

Comment: tried this and it seems to solve my problem. thanks!